# Replace a symbolic variable with a symbolic expression - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've the following code:

```
close all
clear all
syms t
Y=fourier(heaviside(t));
```

The result is Y = pi*dirac(w) - 1i/w. My goal is to replace w with 2*pi*f. How can I do that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Fourier transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fourier.html) syntax. Use following:

```
syms t f
Y=fourier(heaviside(t), 2*pi*f);
```

Comment: Hi @Alexander. Can you help me to solve the inverse problem please? I have an additional 2*pi factor. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882084/inverse-fourier-transform-of-unilateral-exponential-function-ifourier-matlab?noredirect=1#comment76748764_44882084