# Inverse Fourier transform of unilateral exponential function - ifourier MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I get the inverse Fourier tranform of unilateral exponential? I tried with the following code:

```
syms t f
a=sym('a','positive');
y=ifourier(1/(a + pi*f*2i),t)
```

The result is `Y=(exp(-(a*t)/(2*pi))*(sign(t) + 1))/(4*pi)`. Instead I'd like to get `Y=exp(-a*t)*heaviside(t)`.

Comment: Note `(sign(t) + 1)/2 == heaviside(t)`. The different factor of `2*pi` is due to MATLAB's definition of [`fourier`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fourier.html) and [`ifourier`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ifourier.html). See [Wikipedia - Fourier transform - Other conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions) or [Obtaining the $\frac{1}{2π}$ factor in the Fourier transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301860/274245).

Comment: Try to use [simplification](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify-symbolic-expressions.html) of symolic expression.